# Stuck with formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a table for my working hours but I'm stuck in creating formula.

9 people work in the company, and each of them has 200 hrs monthly working hours, but I allow them to exchange working hours as long as they do 1800 hours a month.

Which formula to use for following:

1) deduct time from Worker1 on his monthly hours (column H)

2) add time to Worker2 (column H)

3) check value(s) so hours don't go to negative value

This is an image from the excel table:

[image: Working table]

Answer (score 2):

`=G2+(0-SUMIF(B:B,F2,D:D))+SUMIF(C:C,F2,D:D)`

Original hours, minus the hours they have traded away, plus the hours they have gained via trading...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, formula really used it.

One thing, the issue with "over" added time, like if I add by mistake higher value than available time, then the value goes to negative and that's an error.

Is there a formula to check value and in case negative reply, to cancel operation or return to last value.

On my table, Smith placed 150, which at time was higher value then available hours. How to check this ?

Comment: @DijanaDamjanić I provided the above as it was a simple task, what you ask for now is not only a completely different scope but a much more advanced task that may require VBA... Please have a go at achieving this task and edit in what you have tried (better still create it in a new question referring to this one). We like to see that you've at least tried to solve the issue on your own. This isn't a "free development service", thank you.